# would be + verb(ing) in the future prediction sentences

Tags: phrasal-verbs, subjunctives

Is it OK to use "***would + be+ verb(ing)***" construction when we talk about future projections or predictions. like in this example:

> Over the 50-year period or By 2067, people aged 15 to 59  ***would still be predominating*** the other age groups in the sense of majority

Comment: If you are not sure about the future, use "might", not "would" (you may also use "could"). If you are sure, use "will".

Comment: what would say about that sentence ; "there are plans to upgrade the lobby so that the gallery *would* include an education facility with an adjacent storage and plant room" .  mine is pretty close to this sentence but here *would* is used to signify future probabilty.

Comment: My opinion is: yes, but why?  Why do you want to say "will **be predominating**" instead of "will **predominate**"?

Comment: @stangdon not *will* but *would* what I'm asking about

Comment: @CavidHummatov - Yes, but the issue is the same: why "be predominating" instead of "predominate".  MorganFR's point is also pretty good.  We usually say "X will do Y in the future" or "X might do Y in the future", not "X would do Y in the future".

Comment: @stangdon I thought *be predominating*  would add more the sense of ongoing situation. The fact is true for today and is lıkely to hold true for the future.

Comment: @stangdon  you agreed on the possibility that **would predominate or would be predominating** could be used to signify the future projection, dont you?

Comment: @CavidHummatov - Not really.  Future projections are almost always *will*, not *would*.  I can't really think of a situation where I where use *would* like that.

Comment: **predominate** doesn't work so well in a progressive tense.....

Answer (score 0):

@CavidHummatov it is possible to use this verb tense, but not with this particular combination of verbs.  Things either *predominate* or they don't, there is no ongoing "predomination" possible.  It works better if you choose a subject where *continual action* makes logical sense:

> That old mill has stood by that river since the 1500s, through war and plague and famine and drought.  If the rest of the world goes to hell over the next fifty years, as seems likely, after the dust settles, that mill would still be standing.

Note that I have to provide a pretty complicated setup to justify the verb tense. It's not something you use casually, but to set the image of a very particular time and situation.

Comment: but "would" solely could be used,  did I get it right? *By 2050,  people aged 15 to 59 **would** still predominate the other age groups in the sense of majority*

Comment: Would is generally used in a hypothetical, not the simple future.  There's no "if" statement in your sentence, so there's no reason to use "would".

Comment: then how does the example that has been previously approved as grammatically correct by the community, differ from the one in question  ;  *"there are plans to upgrade the lobby so that the gallery **would** include an education facility with an adjacent storage and plant room"*

Comment: There's an unspoken hypothetical in that sentence.

Comment: could you make it clear for me to see? I can't realize any hypothetical .

Comment: Because the sentence includes "would" it implies"if built" or "if completed".  "...upgrade the lobby so that, if built, the gallery would include ..."  In your sentence it's not clear what the hypothetical would be.

Comment: guess you 're looking for any conditionality to use ***would*** rather than uncertainty. There're several instances that would is used to signify uncertainty, like *"The price of gold would fall by this time next year." , *"That happened a long time ago, I would've been about twenty"* or *"He would seem to be getting better"*

Comment: @CavidHummatov , yes I understand that "would" has a number of meanings.  In this particular structure (talking about a future event) it usually refers to a hypothetical, not uncertainty.  For example, you would not say "this time next year the price of gold **would** fall", at least not without an "if" statement.  If you want to add uncertainty, you say "this time next year, the price of gold (may/might/could/should/will likely/is likely to/might possibly/could potentially/etc.) fall."  **Would** gives it a different meaning.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133576/usage-of-would-for-future

Comment: check that page out, especially Blessed Geek's statement over "using would in non-conditional situations". and tell me do you agree or disagree.

Comment: I don't really agree with, "The bridge would probably fall by next year. It is so old."  I mean, I guess if people say this, then it is what it is, but I prefer "will" unless I'm explicitly in the "imaginary" realm.  But at some point it's a trivial argument, as long as the *meaning* comes across.

Comment: Tell me about ot ! I've never felt that difficulty before in grasping anything  else in English but when it comes to sort out different usages of *would*  I feel like a hopeless swaggie .

Comment: @CavidHummatov I think you get the main idea.  Again, after a certain point, it's all opinion and dialect. Like "swaggie", which means nothing to American me  :)

Answer (score 0):

I admit I have struggled to answer this. At first glance your sentence just *looks wrong*, but the more I analyse it, I can't explain *why* it seems wrong.

The best explanation as to why you may be struggling with this expression, and why I, as a native English speaker find it problematic, is because there are several similar words with varying meanings and tenses.

There are the two root words:

- Dominate (verb) - to have control over
- Dominant (adj) - more important, strong, or noticeable than anything else of the same type

These words are *absolute*. Someone, or something either *is* or *is not* dominant. Likewise, a person either dominates, or does not dominate another.

The words *predominate* and *predominant* have slightly different meanings. They refer to the *most* common, so they are not really absolute.

Assuming you meant to imply "dominating", I would prefer the phrasing:

> "By 2067 people aged 15 to 59 would still **dominate** the other age groups in the sense of majority."

or, at a push:

> "By 2067 people aged 15 to 59 would still **be dominating** the other age groups in the sense of majority."

On the other hand if you meant to use the word "predominant", I would express it this way:

> "By 2067 people aged 15 to 59 **will still be the dominant** age group."

Answer (score 0):

First, since there is no condition involved, "will" is a better fit than "would". For future projections, "would" requires some sense of uncertainty or conditional dependence. @Andrew's answer covers this in detail. For example:

> If the city were to expand its transit network, they would bring in an extra five million in annual revenue.

Second, you have two very different time spans here:

1. Over the fifty-year period: This is a duration. You would use this to express something happening over this entire time, not a single event that happens at the end of it.
2. By 2067: This is a time point. You would use this to point to an event, and not to a progression.

For example:

> Over the fifty-year period, the ozone layer will continue to deplete, and, by 2067, carbon-dioxide concentration will be 1.5 times the current level.

Third, "predominate" is defined as "to be the largest in number or importance" by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predominate). So, it is not an action, but rather a state. A continuous form sounds unnatural. It's like saying "problems will be existing". "Exist", like "predominate", already implies an ongoing state. The continuous form is ambiguous at best. Are you saying that they will be in the process of becoming predominant?

Putting all of this together, I would use the following:

> By 2067, people aged 15 to 59 will predominate population demographics.

Now, I don't know the full context, but if you had even a vague conditional built in, you could use "would".

> Many statistical models forecast a rapid growth in working population over the next fifty years. If these prove accurate, by 2067, people aged 15 to 59 would outnumber all other demographic groups.

The fact that we have a condition on the model's accuracy, the "would" fits more naturally.